# Django: Why am I getting a Value Error?

Tags: python, django, orm, backend, valueerror

The variables are defined before the if statement.

```
if (len(Item.objects.filter(owner=request.session['id'])) > 0):
    for x in Item.objects.filter(owner=request.session['id']):
        if (x.item == forageitem):
            x.amount = x.amount + 1
            x.save()
            messages.success(request, "You found a " + forageitem +".")
            return redirect("/dashboard")
        else:
            continue
```

The function passes through the if statement just fine, but if the item in question is not found, it will not create a new object in the Item class, instead it will give me an error.

For some reason, I am getting a ValueError (didn't get an HttpResponse. Instead it reutunred None.) at this part of my code:

```
else:
    Item.objects.create(item=forageitem, owner=User.objects.get(id = request.session['id']), description=item[forageitem], amount=1)
    messages.success(request, "You found a " + forageitem +".")
    return redirect("/dashboard")
```

I am almost certain I didn't change anything here, it was working before.
Ideas, anyone? Please help.

EDIT: The problem turned out to be int the logic.
I erased the else: statement and made it into a code that runs if it passes through the if: statement without finding anything.

Comment: You need to include the full text of the error, including the traceback.

Comment: This is all that is in the traceback.

Comment: Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Vincent\Desktop\DojoAssignments\Python\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  198.                 "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /forage
Exception Value: The view apps.petsgame_app.views.forage didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: You should edit it into your question, not post it in the comments.

Comment: Can you show us the full definition of the view function, from `def` right until the end, in one solid block? I just want to be absolutely clear on what the code looks like.

Comment: I'm guessing the first if statement actually succeeds, and it goes through the loop, but `if (x.item == forageitem):` always fails and the loop completes without ever returning anything, and that's how the function ends. No explicit return is equivalent to returning `None`. Insert some `print`s into your code to make sure you know exactly that path it's taking.

Comment: If it does not find an instance where x.item == forageitem, it should go on to the else: part of the statement, correct?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I see. My logic was wrong there. It seems to be fixed.